# Soma de valores de acordo com valor de outra coluna

Tags: sql, sqlite3

Tenho duas dúvidas que são difíceis para mim mas que talvez possa ser simples para vocês.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria saber como eu poderia fazer uma soma da quantidade de acordo com as unidades que, neste caso, seriam as unidades `Maracanã`, `Botafogo` e `São Cristóvão`.

E a outra pergunta seria como eu poderia fazer uma soma da quantidade de acordo com cada data, por exemplo, no dia `21/02/2021` teve um total de `1132`.

OBS: Queria saber como fazer em uma query apenas em cada uma das situações para ser possível realizar um plot.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"fazer uma soma da quantidade de acordo com as unidades"***

Para isso, use a função de soma em quantidade, e agrupe por unidade:

```
SELECT unidade,
       SUM(quantidade)
  FROM nome-da-tabela
 GROUP BY unidade
```

***"fazer uma soma da quantidade de acordo com cada data"***

Mesmo conceito, mas aí agrupa-se por data:

```
SELECT data,
       SUM(quantidade)
  FROM nome-da-tabela
 GROUP BY data
```